# How to pass the range of dynamic arrays through loop?

Tags: php

I have the retrieve the table through arrays, now I want to display that array in other table on the bases of user inputs like if user enter 2 then only 2 types tables will appear as well the data of table if user enter 3 three 3 tables with computed data display

Code of table retrieval

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$sa="select * from table1 where c13='$d'";
$result=mysql_query($sa) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>

</tr>";


 $row_count=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    echo $row['c1'];
    echo $row['c2'];
    echo $row['c3'];
    echo $row['c4'];
$a[]=$row['c1'];
        $b[]=$row['c2'];
            $c[]=$row['c3'];
            $d[]=$row['c4'];
$m[]=round(($row['c1']/$row['c4']),2);
                $n[]=round(($row['c2']/$row['c4']),2);
                $o[]=round(($row['c3']/$row['c4']),2);
$row_count++;
 }
echo "Measuring table";
for($i=0;$i<$row_count;$i++) 
{ // do the exploding, the imploding, the row echoing for each row// 
echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
<tr>
<th>Inputs</th>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";

     $f=implode($m,',');
     $r=explode(',',$f);
     print_r($f);
     $f1=implode($n,',');
     $r1=explode(',',$f1);
     print_r($f1);
     $f2=implode($o,',');
     $r2=explode(',',$f2);
     print_r($f2);
echo "<td>" ."W". "</td>";
echo "<td>".$r['0']. "</td>";

 echo "</tr>"; 
echo  "<td>" ."N". "</td>";
echo "<td>".$r1['$i']. "</td>";

 echo "</tr>"; 
echo  "<td>" ."D"."</td>";
echo "<td>".$r2['$i']. "</td>";

 echo "</tr>"; 
 echo "<td>" ."W". "</td>";
echo "<td>".$r['$i']. "</td>";

 echo "</tr>"; 
echo  "<td>" ."N". "</td>";
echo "<td>".$r1['$i']. "</td>";

 echo "</tr>"; 
echo  "<td>" ."D"."</td>";
echo "<td>".$r2['$i']. "</td>";

 echo "</tr>"; 
 </tables>
```

Instead of mentioning array index explicitly it should be display dynamically
result like this

```
c13=2(user enter value)
row1 2 3 4 
row2 4 6 7
```

After retrieval

```
        a       
w       2  
n       3
d       4    // this is of index 0//
w       4
n       6
d       7    // this is of index 1//
```

If now user enter 3, 3 rows will be in the database.

After retrieval

```
w
n
d
w
n
d
w
n
d
```

How can I do this dynamically?

I want that measuring table display dynamically bases on user input. Please help me

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ok sir i will definetaly change ths ?  can u provide help regardng my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before starging the while loop that is retrieving the rows, declare a counter variable.

```
$row_count = 0;
while {
    // loop here
    $row_count++;
}
```

By the end of the row retrieval, $row_count will be holding the... well the row count

** Edit **
To properly echo the measuring table u should structure your code within a for loop

```
echo "Measuring table";
echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
<tr>
<th>Inputs</th>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
</tr>";
for($i=0;$i<$row_count;$i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    $f=implode($m,',');
    $r=explode(',',$f);
    print_r($f);
    $f1=implode($n,',');
    $r1=explode(',',$f1);
    print_r($f1);
    $f2=implode($o,',');
    $r2=explode(',',$f2);
    print_r($f2);
    echo "<td>" ."W". "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$r[$i]. "</td>";

    echo "</tr>"; 
    echo  "<td>" ."N". "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$r1[$i]. "</td>";

    echo "</tr>"; 
    echo  "<td>" ."D"."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$r2[$i]. "</td>";

    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: then sir what i do with table "measuring table"

Comment: The next step would be structuring the measuring table echoing code, within a for loop for example. `for($i=0;$i<$row_count;$i++) { // do the exploding, the imploding, the row echoing for each row }`

Comment: Im not sure what you are really trying to achieve with your code, but the editing i made to my post might help you. Modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks sir i done the same way its working thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to help you. Godd luck coding.

Comment: sir i have one more question can we defined the index of current data like if there is lot of data in the datbase but i want to display only the current data for example if one user enter 2 the data of only two rows will be display next when other user enter again 2 in my case all data havng 2 will display ? could it possible that i defined something for current user mean if user 1 enter 2 only 2 rows of that user display if other enter 2 only two rows of that user display

Comment: Yes that is possible, but could be relatively complex to achieve. First you need to find a way to 'identify', in your php code, wich user is filling the input. Second you need to read the database based on the user. To achieve this, your database must provide some sort of User table. In that case, your sql query stored in $sa must be modified so that it includes a JOIN with the users table and a conditional WHERE to select rows concerning one specific user.

Comment: sir i am not menting the user name can it possible if i set timestamp in the database on the bases of current time i fetch the data

Comment: sir can u guide any way  of it